# Must load PHP page twice to load session file data into an array

Tags: php, fpm

I am running the [PHP:FPM container on Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/php). I start a session, create a session ID, and then use print_r to display the session data.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
  print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
```

I get the following output which shows that the session ID is as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5.

```
Array ( [id] => as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5 )
```

And in the container, I can see the session file exists, owned by www-data, and is 37 bytes (contains data).

```
[jeremy.canfield@docker1 ~]$ sudo docker exec php-fpm ls -l /usr/local/sessions
-rw-------. 1 www-data www-data 37 Feb 19 03:03 sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5
```

And the session file contains ID as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5.

```
[jeremy.canfield@docker1 ~]$ sudo docker exec php-fpm cat /usr/local/sessions/sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5
id|s:26:"as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5";
```

Let's say I do this, using the [file function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read the /usr/local/sessions/sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5 file.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
  echo "I am " . exec('whoami');
  $file = file("/usr/local/sessions/sess_$_SESSION[id]");
  print_r ($file);
?>
```

The first time I load this page, I can see that I am the www-data user, and thus have read access to the /usr/local/sessions/sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5 file, but the print_r ($file) command is returning an empty array, meaning **the file function failed to load the content of /usr/local/sessions/sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5 into the $file array**.

```
I am www-data
Array ( )
```

Then I reload my PHP page and the following is returned, showing that the file function successfully loaded the content of the /usr/local/sessions/sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5 file into the $file array.

```
I am www-data
Array ( [0] => id|s:26:"as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5"; )
```

I am not sure how to get the $file array to contain the content of the /usr/local/sessions/sess_as84kcq75m8ev6a7srv8nutak5 file the first time the PHP page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Session is supposed to be read and write using merely the `$_SESSION` super global array and the `session_start()` function. There is no good reason to deal with the raw session file format (which probably is simply array of [serialized strings](https://www.php.net/serialize) that you can [unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize).)

If you want more control with your session data (e.g. access all the session data of your user, control how they are expired), you should write your own [SessionHandler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) implementation and then [set it as your session handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). If you know how to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), you can even find existing implementations of session handlers for [mysql](https://packagist.org/?query=session%20mysql), [mongodb](https://packagist.org/?query=session%20mongodb) or other backends.

Comment: Thanks @Koala for your comment. I'll do my due diligence and work through the idea you shared here.